# C# - Best (fastest) way to import data from text file to mdf

Tags: c#, database, text, file

I need to import data from text file (not separeted by commas, other way, different characters) to database (for example to mdf). Because datagridview loads data from database faster then from file. What is the best way?
Thank you

Comment: How much data are you talking about? Is the data relational? How have you tested the performance?

Comment: How are you processing the data such that it is slower to access a local file? I *can write* a sample pushing it into a DB, but I think this is the wrong way to go here (if you currently have a file)

Comment: I am talking about 200MB text files which has thousands and thousands line of code. I was trying do it first read every line, give it to class (made for data) then to arraylist and using foreach loop tried create sqlcommand and add columns as parameters. It worked but it was importing so long so I think there is better way.

Comment: I tested performance by DateTime now when I started with parsing data and DateTime.Now.Subtract when everything was done. Text file was loaded 24s and database 10s.

Comment: Try wrapping everything in a database transaction. This can speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using SQL Server (which .mdf suggests you are) you could try bulk inserting:

```
BULK
INSERT MyTable
FROM 'c:\myfile.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Columns in my text file are not separated by 1 unique character but there are different characters which divided columns (like ",","]","[" ...). I have function for reading lines and divide them into columns but not sure what is best to do now.

Comment: In that case I would suggest pre-parsing the files to make them conform to csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the .NET library [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) can do something for you...